# Eclipse + Wildfly + Maven EAR project, is it possible to have files update without redeploy?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2.2, wildfly-8

I'm working on my first JavaEE/JSF project. It's currently set up with maven so that several jars and a war are deployed inside an EAR container.  I spent a lot of time trying to get some kind of hot/autoredeploy type setup going a few weeks ago but gave up and have been doing it manually.  The problem i'm having is the maven build has grown to be time consuming and it takes upwards of a full two minutes to build and deploy. When i'm making a small change to an xhtml or css file it would be nice to not have to redeploy the app. I assume to do this i need both the ear and the war to be deployed exploded.  How can i accomplish this with maven and eclipse? Is there a tutorial that i haven't found? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Not natively. Just use an advanced hotdeploy plugin. Which one to choose is in turn primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wan't to disagree with BlagusC (the one and only here ;-) ) but for normal changes "hotdeployment" should work fine. Only if you change backing beans structure (e.g.: add methods, add classes) restart is needed.

Important thing is that you start the server in debug mode - here are my server settings:

Overview Tab:
[image: Overview Tab]

Deployment Tab:
[image: Deployment Tab]

For xhtml and css files this works fine!

Comment: You shouldn't need to use debug mode for hotdeployment to work though, should you? I use it with Glassfish all the time, not in debug mode.